# Thymeleaf - boolean operators

Tags: html, boolean, operators, thymeleaf

How can I use boolean operators like `and` or `or` using Thymeleaf?

For instance, if I want to show the data from a table if only one of the conditions is true.

```
<tr th:if="firstCondition or secondCondition">
  <td th:text="${entity.attr1}"</td>
  <td th:text="${entity.attr2}">Default Value</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: `${entity.attr1} or ${entity.attr2}`.  Same with `and`.

Comment: I need something like this:  <tr th:if="${violation.remainingDebt != 0} or ${violation.validity == true}">. But only the second condition works.

Comment: Both conditions work isolated

Answer (score 17):

Boolean operators work just like that. You use 'or', 'and' instead of the normal java nomenclature. You can also shorten your ifs.

You can try this:

```
<tr th:if="${violation.remainingDebt != 0 or violation.validity}">
```

You need to nest them up in the same curly brackets, independently if they are isolated considering the logical 'or' operation being tested.

Be wary though! This will only show you the tr and it's child elements if the if passes as true.

Answer (score 15):

Instead of using conditional operators `&&` and `||` in the expression like we use in Java and Javascript, in Thymeleaf we use the text `AND` and `OR` for comparison.

`OR` condition example:

```
<div th:if="${fruit.name} == Apple OR ${fruit.name} == Orange ">
     <!-- fruit's name is either Apple or Orange -->
</div>
```

`AND` condition example:

```
<div th:if="${user.role} == 'ADMIN' AND ${user.property} == 'SPECIAL' ">
     <!-- User is admin and has SPECIAL previleges -->
</div>
```