# thymeleaf not allowing using `&&` in form

Tags: angularjs, thymeleaf

Hi i'm learning angular with my sprig mvc application.i'm using Thymeleaf for templating . But when use form submit with angular form validation , i need to use `&&` with ng-submit. When running application thymeleaf does not allow me to use `&&`

```
<form role="form" name="stationform" novalidate="novalidate"
      ng-submit="stationform.$valid && addStation(station)">

</form>
```

**Exception i got**

```
ERROR: org.thymeleaf.templateparser.ErrorHandler - [THYMELEAF][http-nio-8181-exec-9] Fatal error during parsing
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 20; columnNumber: 97; The entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:198)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:177)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:441)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:368)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(XMLScanner.java:1436)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.scanAttributeValue(XMLScanner.java:885)
```

Comment: Have you tried `and` ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18006941/thymeleaf-boolean-operators

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A standalone `&` is illegal in HTML but usually works due to the leniency of browser parsing. Truth is, everyone should be using `&amp;` instead. In your case, you have no choice due to Thymeleaf parsing being much stricter than your browser's, so you *need* to use `&amp;&amp;` instead of `&&`. Note that it’s also true for `>` and `<` in expressions (e.g. you’ll need to write `ng-if="a &gt; b"` instead of `ng-if="a > b"`).

Answer (score 3):

you can use "and" insted of && 
bonus: use "or" instead of ||

All of them (&& || ) are used in javascript only!

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?