# Thymeleaf "or" operator in th:if

Tags: html, thymeleaf

I am wondering what the correct syntax for having an Or operator within thymeleaf.

I'm basing my solution off this stack post:

[Thymeleaf - boolean operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18006941/thymeleaf-boolean-operators)

Where the top voted answer uses "or".

My current code:

```
 th:if="${not #strings.startsWith(inbox?.status, 'P')}"
```

Is checking if the inbox.status does not begin with p, if this is the case the text will be displayed, which works fine.

Now I want to check that the inbox status doesn't begin with 'App' as well, like so:

```
th:if="${not #strings.startsWith(inbox?.status, 'P') or not #strings.startsWith(inbox.status, 'App')}"
```

But this is doing nothing.

Comment: th:if="${not #strings.startsWith(inbox?.status, 'P') or !(#strings.startsWith(inbox.status, 'App'))}"

Comment: @GoutamS I tried this solution, it is working correctly up until the "or" part, after the "or" it doesn't seem the be reading it.

Comment: Shouldn't you be using AND for this?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `OR` or `||`.  In your case however, it it's the logic of you expression that is incorrect.

```
Status    A                 B                   !A || !B
          startsWith('P')   startsWith('App')   
Pending   true              false               true
App       false             true                true
Something false             false               true
```

I would personally write this as (note that I'm using `th:unless` rather than `th:if`):

```
th:unless="${#strings.startsWith(inbox?.status, 'P') OR #strings.startsWith(inbox?.status, 'App')}"
```

Comment: Ah! That makes complete sense, I have implemented "th:unless" into my code and it is working as I wanted it to!